# Backbone js: change event clobbering click event

Tags: events, backbone.js

I've got an order form with fields including a textarea and a 'COMMIT' button. The fields are autosaving, i.e. the moment a field's value changes, it is saved to the db. The COMMIT button changes the order's status to 'committed', saving that too.

The problem comes when the user types into the textarea, then, without leaving the field, clicks on 'COMMIT'. The textarea's change event is triggered, but this seems to defeat the button click. I have to click the COMMIT button a second time.

How can I get both events to fire? (They need to fire independently, since the user is free to edit fields and click COMMIT however she chooses. I sure can't have the updateInstructions method directly trigger the commit!)

Teh codez:

```
events: {
    "change textarea"       : "updateInstructions",
    "click .btnCommit"      : "btnCommit",
},

updateInstructions: function(e){
    var target = $(e.currentTarget),
        name = target.attr('name'),
        value = target.val(),
        data = {};
    data[name] = value;
    this.model.save(data, {
        success: function(model, response){
            //handle response
        },
        wait: true,
        patch: true
    });
},
btnCommit: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
this.updateOrderStatus(this.ORDER_STATUS_SUBMITTED);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Intead of using change in the event, use blur 
like this, and I think that would be enough.

```
events: {
    "blur textarea"       : "updateInstructions",
    "click .btnCommit"      : "btnCommit",
},
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. We seem to have moved away from that user interaction model.